# Match dates with different formats in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to match the boot up time with the file modified date to be within a couple minutes of each other.

I can get the data but don't know how to do the computations.  Here is what I get:

```
PS E:\> $disk=gci -Attributes hidden E:\filename.ext | Select LastWriteTime
PS E:\> $disk

LastWriteTime
-------------
6/23/2014 12:55:48 PM

PS E:\> $boottime=Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select last bootuptime
PS E:\> $boottime
lastbootuptime
--------------
6/23/2014 12:55:39 PM
```

What I am looking for in English is a way to say "If lastwritetime is within 5 minutes of lastboot time, then all is good.  If not, all is bad"

How can I do that with powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would subtract the datetimes and use the resulting TimeSpan object.  Also, note that using the -ExpandProperty is needed to get a bare value with select-object.

```
$disk=gci -Attributes hidden E:\filename.ext | Select -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime

$boottime=Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select -ExpandProperty lastbootuptime

if(($disk-$bootTime).TotalMinutes -lt 5){
  "all is good"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, those are both dates and times, that's for sure. The issue is that the Get-WMI is returning some crazy CimInstance object that is relatively useless. What you **can** do with that is feed it to Get-Date, and that produces a [DateTime] object, and that is very useful! Try this out:

```
$boottime=get-date (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select -expand lastbootuptime)
```

Then you can do something like:

```
IF($Disk.Lastwritetime -lt $boottime.addminutes(5)){"All is good!"} else {"There is a disturbance in the force!"}
```